# How to get the displayName of a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I've put all my Jenkins logic in a structured pipeline script (aka Jenkinsfile).

If something goes wrong, i m sending mails. For the subject i want to use the `displayName` of the job and not the jobs id `env.JOB_NAME` (as they are driven by access control patterns and not readability).

With a normal pipeline job i could use `currentBuild.rawBuild.project.displayName` but for multibranch pipelines this is just the branch name.

Or is there a even better way to get the userfriendly name, then traversing the rawBuild?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now i found no convinient public api, so this seems to be the way to go:

```
String getDisplayName(currentBuild) {
    def project = currentBuild.rawBuild.project

    // for multibranch pipelines
    if (project.parent instanceof WorkflowMultiBranchProject) {
        return "${project.parent.displayName} (${project.displayName})"
    } else {
        // for all other projects
        return project.displayName
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `currentBuild` a global rather than an input parameter?

Comment: You are right Blake, but i use this code as static function in a class provided by a shared library so i had to pass the `currentBuild` as parameter in order to use it. If you define the function in your pipeline you don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

I use `currentBuild.fullProjectName` which is set to `multibranch_pipeline_name/branch_name` or `pipeline_name` depending if you are using a multibranch pipeline or normal pipeline.